# use the If else condition for selecting the column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am having two tables like this.Both are separate tables

```
AccountNo       User         Name
----------------------------------
 1               U            a
 2               U            b
 3               U            c
```

And another table contains the following structure

```
 TempAccountNo       Mycolumn    AccountNo     
------------------------------------------
 4               X                2341
 5               Y                 2
 6               Z                2568
```

I need to select the   AccountNo or TempAccountNo,Mycolumn From table II and the condition is

```
If (tableII.AccountNo not in table I)

   I need to choose `TempAccountNo from table II`

else
  I need to choose `AccountNo from table II`
```

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```sql
SELECT IF(
    t1.AccountNo IS NULL, -- condition
    t2.TempAccountNo,     -- true branch
    t2.AccountNo          -- false branch
  ) AS optional_field
FROM table2 t2
  LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.AccountNo = t2.AccountNo
```

Comment: Why is this the most accepted answer? What does it do?

Answer (score 38):

I have a mysql query for multiple select field using if ... else statements or using case statement. This is described below.

1. MYSQL select using if statement

   ```
   select IF('fieldname with condition','if true value','if false value') from table_name where 1;
   ```
2. MYSQL select using multiple if else

   ```
   select 
     CASE
       WHEN fieldname1 = 'value1' THEN 'if true then give value'
       WHEN fieldname2 = 'value2' THEN 'if true then give value' THEN 'if true then give value'
       WHEN fieldname3 = 'value3' THEN 'if true then give value' THEN 'if true then give value' 
       WHEN fieldname4 = 'value4' THEN 'if true then give value' THEN 'if true then give value'
       ELSE 'else all false then give default value'
     END as STATUS,
   from table_name where 1;
   ```

Try using these queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(t1.AccountNo IS NULL, t2.TempAccountNo, t2.AccountNo) AS Acc_common
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.AccountNo = t2.AccountNo
```

This will help..