# How to use IF condition for column selection in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2

In my project I want data from same table in 2 different manner.
1) Only 5 fields
2) Only 10 fields
And I am getting the data through `Stored Procedure` for each one. But I want that if possible I should make one procedure.

> So, can I put if condition for selecting column?

For example, if I pass parameter as "**Less**", it will get data of only 5 columns and if I pass parameter as "**More**", it will get data of 10 columns. I can have two `SELECT` statement in procedure based on condition(that I have already done) but I want to make it One `SELECT` statement. Is it possible?

Comment: Okie... Actually I refered this post. So I thought might be there is a way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688782/use-the-if-else-condition-for-selecting-the-column-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, is it not possible to have a single SELECT statement.

But then, you can do this:

```
if @ColumnList = 'less'
begin
    call storedProc_returning5Columns
end
else
begin
    call storedProc_returning10Columns
end
```

[Another option is to use Dynamic TSQL]

Comment: Actually I have other parameters also for deciding SELECT Query and My Store procedure has almost 8 select statement so I though if I can have better approach.

Comment: even better this way then. Code will be more understandable and more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.

Your current solution of having an `IF` statement in the stored procedure is the best approach.