# Select multiple columns using single if condition

Tags: mysql

I have tried the below query but somehow it's not working for me. Can anyone tell me why?

Query :

```
SELECT column1
     , column2
     , IF(start <="20:00:00" AND end >= "20:00:00")
          THEN (column3,column4,column5)
          ELSE (column6,column7,column8)
       END IF
     , column9
     , column10
FROM table_1
WHERE id ="1"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763310/how-do-write-if-else-statement-in-a-mysql-query this might help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do write IF ELSE statement in a MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763310/how-do-write-if-else-statement-in-a-mysql-query)

Comment: @PeterAbolins : Thanks for reply,I am trying to fetch multiple columns based on single if condition but somehow it's not allow me to do it.

Comment: @waka This question have single value while i want to select multiple columns.I know how to use condition for single column but don't know how to make with multiple columns

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is incorrent, you can't use `if` this way.

But you can do it this way:

```
select 
  column1,column2, column3,column4,column5,column9,column10 
from table 1 
where id ="1" AND (start <="20:00:00"  AND end >= "20:00:00")
UNION ALL
select 
  column1,column2, column6,column7,column8,column9,column10 
from table 1 
where id ="1" AND (start >= "20:00:00"  AND end <= "20:00:00");
```

However, in order for this to work correctly, the columns `column3,column4,column5` and `column6,column7,column8` should be of the same data type respectively. Otherwise, you might need to cast them into one data type. (Thanks for the note @Peter Abolins)

Comment: It might make sense to point out that columns 3, 4 and 5 need to have identical types to columns 6, 7 and 8 correspondingly, or the above will fail.

Comment: @PeterAbolins -  You are correct, `UNION` will fail if the types are different. Thanks for the note. I will update the answer.

Comment: @DarwinThorburn : I have tried this is not working in my case.

Comment: I need something like if condition is not going to satisfied then it must need to provide me result of else condition but you have put both condition in opposite way in both queries

Answer (score 0):

That isn't how if statements work in mysql.

In mysql it would be more like

```
if(some condition, is true return this, is false return this)
```

so

```
if(1 = 1, do this, else do this)
```

You can chain them as well so

```
if(1 = 1, if(2 = 2, do this, else this), else this)
```

It can be pretty confusing if you come from a programming background, but I think you should check out the [mysql docs on control flow functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html).

Check out [this answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6438703/8378419) for a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish. I think you're better off with case statements but an if could work as well. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've came from the future after battling with this issue.
For whom it may concern and for own reasons objects using UNION statements, you might as well use JSON_OBJECT statements:

```
SELECT column1
     , column2
     , (IF(start <="20:00:00" AND end >= "20:00:00"),
          JSON_OBJECT("column3", column3,
                      "column4", column4,
                      "column5", column5
                      ) as result,
          JSON_OBJECT("column6", column6
                      "column7", column7
                      "column8", column8
                      ) as result,
     , column9
     , column10
FROM table_1
WHERE id ="1"
```

Support for JSON operators can be found after MySQL 5.7. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html